# What is a mixing process?

Tags: normal-distribution, mixture-distribution, finance, gaussian-mixture-distribution

What does this mean?

> Asset prices follow a mixture of normal distributions with a mixing process dependent on the unobservable information arrival process.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a financial example on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model#A_financial_model).  The basic idea is that at different times asset prices are drawn from different gaussian distributions.  For example, maybe sometimes (boom) asset prices are drawn from a distribution with a higher mean, and sometimes (bust) they are drawn from a distribution with a lower mean.  Unfortunately, at any given time we don't know whether we are in a boom or a bust.  The goal of estimating mixture models is to jointly estimate the mean and variance of the N gaussian distributions and the probability that current prices are being drawn from each of the N distributions.